# sudoku solver: not giving any output using this program

Tags: python, sudoku

```
    grid=[[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],
          [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
          [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
          [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
          [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
          [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
          [0,0,0,0,0,6,2,8,0],
          [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
          [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]
    print(grid)
    import numpy as np
    print(np.matrix(grid))
    def possible(y,x,n):
        global grid
        for i in range(9):
            if grid [y][i]==n:
                return False
        for j in range(9):
            if grid[j][x]==n:
                return False
        x0=(x//3)*3
        y0=(y//3)*3
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if grid[y0+i][x0+j]==n:
                    return False
        return True    
    def solve():
        global grid
        for y in range(9):
            for x in range(9):
                if grid[y][x]==0:
                    for n in range(1,10):
                        if possible(y,x,n):
                            grid[y][x]=n
                            solve()
                            grid[y][x]=0
                    """print(np.matrix(grid))"""      
                    return 
        print(np.matrix(grid))        
        input('More?')                
 solve()
```

Iam trying to solvve the sudoku puzzel with this program but something is wrong with the solve function
program is not giving any output and including print(np.matrix(grid)) this line into the code will give many outputs containing zeros. heres my code so far.

Comment: What is the line grid[y][x]=0`enter code here`  doing?

Comment: Looks like the indenting is off in various places.  Maybe check with where you got this code from.